# Reading ASCII character causes an infinite loop

Tags: c, while-loop, ascii

If you enter integer value the loop works just fine but if you enter some ASCII character or `float` type value the program goes into an infinite loop. Any fix for this issue?
Technically, `char` is one type of `int` so this shouldn't be a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int num;

  scanf("%d",&num);
  while (num < 40)
  {
    printf("Number is small\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: scanf stops on non-digit so it is better to use fgets when reading lines from a user.

Comment: Just don't worry about it for now.  Seriously.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin/58884121#58884121) for justification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will try to read a decimal integer from `stdin`. It uses the definition of a decimal integer from [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol):

> The valid integer value consists of the following parts:

- (optional) plus or minus sign
- (optional) prefix (0) indicating octal base (applies only when the base is 8 or ​0​)
- (optional) prefix (0x or 0X) indicating hexadecimal base (applies only when the base is 16 or ​0​)
- a sequence of digits

In other words, `scanf` will try to *interpret* a sequence of characters on `stdin` as a decimal integer. It will *not* do a character to integer conversion based on the ASCII table.

The solution to your problem lies in checking the return value of `scanf`, which is:

> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

So, check if `scanf` did not return 1. In this case, it has not read a decimal integer and `num` has not been assigned a value and should not be used.
In the given program, if `num` has never been assigned a value, its value is indeterminate. This could be a value <40, explaining the infinite loop as `scanf` repeatedly tries to read a non-integer from `stdin`, fails and leaves the non-integer on `stdin` as is. If `num` has been assigned a value before, it will still hold that value after a failed `scanf` call.